# Browser Router and axios and dependencies in local environment

Tags: reactjs, npm, directory, axios

I used 'npm i axios' and other things like react router dom and stuff on my computer.

Now I didn't install them in the directory but the folder above.

So I have 3 folders. The main folder, then inside I have a folder called 'frontend' and 'backend'. frontend was made using create-react-app.

Now instead of installing npm i axios inside the frontend folder, I installed it inside the main folder.

But it still works.

What is the scope of these packages?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

look at your package.json file if it shows you

```
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "version number",
 }
```

its means that you have already install npm i axios in frontend folder , npm i must have to be executed in project directory